# Can't get phpxdebug running

Tags: php

I cannot get PHP X Debug working. It will not let me select any breakpoints, and when I go to localhost:9000 or 8080 it doesn't load.
I cannot get PHP X Debug working. It will not let me select any breakpoints, and when I go to localhost:9000 or 8080 it doesn't load.
I cannot get PHP X Debug working. It will not let me select any breakpoints, and when I go to localhost:9000 or 8080 it doesn't load.
I cannot get PHP X Debug working. It will not let me select any breakpoints, and when I go to localhost:9000 or 8080 it doesn't load.
I cannot get PHP X Debug working. It will not let me select any breakpoints, and when I go to localhost:9000 or 8080 it doesn't load.
phpinfo():

```html
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 8.0.0

System => Windows NT DESKTOP-1GCBMNO 10.0 build 19041 (Windows 10) AMD64
Build Date => Nov 24 2020 21:54:22
Build System => Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard [10.0.14393]
Compiler => Visual C++ 2019
Architecture => x64
Configure Command => cscript /nologo /e:jscript configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\dep-aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\dep-aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>
Loaded Configuration File => D:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20200930
PHP Extension => 20200930
Zend Extension => 420200930
Zend Extension Build => API420200930,TS,VS16
PHP Extension Build => API20200930,TS,VS16
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => enabled
Thread API => Windows Threads
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 8.0.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => D:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini => D:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log => D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => D:\xampp\php\ext => D:\xampp\php\ext
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => D:\xampp\php\PEAR => D:\xampp\php\PEAR
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 512M => 512M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 40M => 40M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => no value => no value
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl
syslog.ident => php => php
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 40M => 40M
upload_tmp_dir => D:\xampp\tmp => D:\xampp\tmp
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
windows.show_crt_warning => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.exception_ignore_args => Off => Off
zend.exception_string_param_max_len => 15 => 15
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.73.0
Age => 7
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => No
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => Yes
TLS-SRP => No
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => No
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => No
HTTPS_PROXY => Yes
MULTI_SSL => No
BROTLI => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-win32
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1h
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.9.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
curl.cainfo => D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt => D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt

date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2020.02
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2020.4
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Berlin

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.833333 => 90.833333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.833333 => 90.833333
date.timezone => Europe/Berlin => Europe/Berlin

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.10
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG, TIFF
Multibyte decoding support using mbstring => enabled
Extended EXIF tag formats => Canon, Casio, Fujifilm, Nikon, Olympus, Samsung, Panasonic, DJI, Sony, Pentax, Minolta, Sigma, Foveon, Kyocera, Ricoh, AGFA, Epson

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
libmagic => 539

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled

gettext
```

Comment: Hi! Please read the article "How to ask" from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you sure your question / answer is usefull ?, can you please put more effort in explaing issue/fix ?

Answer (score -1):

I have done the following steps:

```html
Install XDebug I highly recommend you make a simple test.php file, put a phpinfo(); statement in there, then copy the output and paste it into the XDebug installation wizard. It will analyze it and give you tailored installation instructions for your environment. In short:

On Windows: Download the appropiate precompiled DLL for your PHP version, architecture (64/32 Bit), thread safety (TS/NTS) and Visual Studio compiler version and place it in your PHP extension folder.
On Linux: Either download the source code as a tarball or clone it with git, then compile it.
Configure PHP to use XDebug by adding zend_extension=path/to/xdebug to your php.ini. The path of your php.ini is shown in your phpinfo() output under "Loaded Configuration File".

Enable remote debugging in your php.ini:

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
There are other ways to tell XDebug to connect to a remote debugger than remote_autostart, like cookies, query parameters or browser extensions. I recommend remote_autostart because it "just works". There are also a variety of other options, like the port (by default 9000), please see the XDebug documentation on remote debugging for more information.

If you are doing web development, don't forget to restart your webserver to reload the settings.

Verify your installation by checking your phpinfo() output for an XDebug section.
```

Here is summary oh phpinfo():

Summary
Xdebug installed: 3.0.1
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: yes
Compiler: MS VS16
Architecture: x64
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 8.0.0
Zend API nr: 420200930
PHP API nr: 20200930
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
OPcache Loaded: no
Extensions directory: D:\xampp\php\ext

Comment: Why post this as an answer? Edit your question and paste relevant info there, this way you could have avoided the useless repetition of text in your question

Answer (score -2):

TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest

```html
    GetText Support => enabled

    hash

    hash support => enabled
    Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

    MHASH support => Enabled
    MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

    iconv

    iconv support => enabled
    iconv implementation => "libiconv"
    iconv library version => 1.16

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    iconv.input_encoding => no value => no value
    iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
    iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value

    json

    json support => enabled

    libxml

    libXML support => active
    libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.10
    libXML Loaded Version => 20910
    libXML streams => enabled

    mbstring

    Multibyte Support => enabled
    Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
    HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
    libmbfl version => 1.3.2

    mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

    Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
    Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 6.9.6

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
    mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
    mbstring.http_input => no value => no value
    mbstring.http_output => no value => no value
    mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
    mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
    mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
    mbstring.regex_retry_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
    mbstring.regex_stack_limit => 100000 => 100000
    mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
    mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

    mysqli

    MysqlI Support => enabled
    Client API library version => mysqlnd 8.0.0
    Active Persistent Links => 0
    Inactive Persistent Links => 0
    Active Links => 0

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    mysqli.allow_local_infile => Off => Off
    mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
    mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
    mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
    mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
    mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
    mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
    mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
    mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
    mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
    mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off

    mysqlnd

    mysqlnd => enabled
    Version => mysqlnd 8.0.0
    Compression => supported
    core SSL => supported
    extended SSL => supported
    Command buffer size => 4096
    Read buffer size => 32768
    Read timeout => 86400
    Collecting statistics => Yes
    Collecting memory statistics => Yes
    Tracing => n/a
    Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
    API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql

    openssl

    OpenSSL support => enabled
    OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
    OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
    Openssl default config => C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/openssl.cnf

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    openssl.cafile => D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt => D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
    openssl.capath => no value => no value

    pcre

    PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
    PCRE Library Version => 10.35 2020-05-09
    PCRE Unicode Version => 13.0.0
    PCRE JIT Support => enabled
    PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
    pcre.jit => 1 => 1
    pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

    PDO

    PDO support => enabled
    PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite

    pdo_mysql

    PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
    Client API version => mysqlnd 8.0.0

    pdo_sqlite

    PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
    SQLite Library => 3.33.0

    Phar

    Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
    Phar API version => 1.1.1
    Phar-based phar archives => enabled
    Tar-based phar archives => enabled
    ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
    gzip compression => enabled
    bzip2 compression => enabled
    OpenSSL support => enabled


    Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
    Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
    Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    phar.cache_list => no value => no value
    phar.readonly => On => On
    phar.require_hash => On => On

    readline

    Readline Support => enabled
    Readline library => WinEditLine

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    cli.pager => no value => no value
    cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \>

    Reflection

    Reflection => enabled

    session

    Session Support => enabled
    Registered save handlers => files user
    Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    session.auto_start => Off => Off
    session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
    session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
    session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
    session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
    session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
    session.cookie_path => / => /
    session.cookie_samesite => no value => no value
    session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
    session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
    session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
    session.lazy_write => On => On
    session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
    session.referer_check => no value => no value
    session.save_handler => files => files
    session.save_path => D:\xampp\tmp => D:\xampp\tmp
    session.serialize_handler => php => php
    session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
    session.sid_length => 26 => 26
    session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
    session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
    session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
    session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
    session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
    session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
    session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
    session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
    session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

    SimpleXML

    SimpleXML support => enabled
    Schema support => enabled

    SPL

    SPL support => enabled
    Interfaces => OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
    Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

    standard

    Dynamic Library Support => enabled
    Internal Sendmail Support for Windows => enabled

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    assert.active => On => On
    assert.bail => Off => Off
    assert.callback => no value => no value
    assert.exception => On => On
    assert.warning => On => On
    auto_detect_line_endings => Off => Off
    default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
    from => no value => no value
    session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
    session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
    unserialize_max_depth => 4096 => 4096
    url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
    url_rewriter.tags => form= => form=
    user_agent => no value => no value

    tokenizer

    Tokenizer Support => enabled

    xdebug

    __   __   _      _
    \ \ / /  | |    | |
     \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _
      > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
     / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
    /_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                                  __/ |
                                 |___/

    Version => 3.0.1
    Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

    Feature => Enabled/Disabled
    Development Aids => ✔ enabled
    Coverage => ✘ disabled
    GC Stats => ✘ disabled
    Profiler => ✘ disabled
    Step Debugger => ✘ disabled
    Tracing => ✘ disabled

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    xdebug.auto_trace => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.auto_trace" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.auto_trace"
    xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
    xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
    xdebug.client_host => localhost => localhost
    xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
    xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
    xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
    xdebug.collect_includes => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_includes" => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_includes"
    xdebug.collect_params => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_params" => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_params"
    xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
    xdebug.collect_vars => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_vars" => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.collect_vars"
    xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
    xdebug.coverage_enable => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.coverage_enable" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.coverage_enable"
    xdebug.default_enable => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.default_enable" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.default_enable"
    xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
    xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
    xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
    xdebug.dump_once => On => On
    xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
    xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
    xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
    xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
    xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
    xdebug.gc_stats_enable => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.gc_stats_enable" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.gc_stats_enable"
    xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir"
    xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
    xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
    xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
    xdebug.log => no value => no value
    xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
    xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
    xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
    xdebug.mode => develop => develop
    xdebug.output_dir => C:\Windows\Temp => C:\Windows\Temp
    xdebug.overload_var_dump => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.overload_var_dump" => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.overload_var_dump"
    xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
    xdebug.profiler_enable => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable"
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger"
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value"
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_output_dir" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.profiler_output_dir"
    xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
    xdebug.remote_autostart => 1 => 1
    xdebug.remote_connect_back => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_connect_back" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_connect_back"
    xdebug.remote_enable => 1 => 1
    xdebug.remote_host => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_host" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_host"
    xdebug.remote_log => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_log" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_log"
    xdebug.remote_log_level => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_log_level" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_log_level"
    xdebug.remote_mode => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_mode" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_mode"
    xdebug.remote_port => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_port" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_port"
    xdebug.remote_timeout => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_timeout" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.remote_timeout"
    xdebug.scream => Off => Off
    xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
    xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
    xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
    xdebug.show_mem_delta => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.show_mem_delta" => This setting has been removed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-"xdebug.show_mem_delta"
    xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
    xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
    xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_enable_trigger" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_enable_trigger"
    xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value"
    xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
    xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
    xdebug.trace_output_dir => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_output_dir" => This setting has been changed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-"xdebug.trace_output_dir"
    xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
    xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
    xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
    xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
    xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3

    xml

    XML Support => active
    XML Namespace Support => active
    libxml2 Version => 2.9.10

    xmlreader

    XMLReader => enabled

    xmlwriter

    XMLWriter => enabled

    zip

    Zip => enabled
    Zip version => 1.19.1
    Libzip version => 1.7.1

    zlib

    ZLib Support => enabled
    Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
    Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
    Compiled Version => 1.2.11
    Linked Version => 1.2.11

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
    zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
    zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

    Additional Modules

    Module Name

    Environment

    Variable => Value
    ALLUSERSPROFILE => C:\ProgramData
    APPDATA => C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Roaming
    CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME => \\.\pipe\crashpad_828_XYPHVDMQVQHPQSLA
    CommonProgramFiles => C:\Program Files\Common Files
    CommonProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    CommonProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    ComSpec => C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
    DriverData => C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
    HOMEDRIVE => C:
    HOMEPATH => \Users\Grkem
    LOCALAPPDATA => C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local
    LOGONSERVER => \\DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS => 4
    OneDrive => C:\Users\Grkem\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Bielefeld
    OneDriveCommercial => C:\Users\Grkem\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Bielefeld
    ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP => undefined
    OS => Windows_NT
    Path => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\bin;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\gstreamer-ivao\bin;C:\gstreamer-ivao\x86\bin;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Grkem\.dotnet\tools
    PATHEXT => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE => AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER => Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL => 6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION => 9e09
    ProgramData => C:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles => C:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files
    PSModulePath => C:\Users\Grkem\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
    PUBLIC => C:\Users\Public
    SESSIONNAME => Console
    SystemDrive => C:
    SystemRoot => C:\WINDOWS
    TEMP => C:\Users\GRKEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    TMP => C:\Users\GRKEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    USERDOMAIN => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    USERNAME => Grkem
    USERPROFILE => C:\Users\Grkem
    windir => C:\WINDOWS
    TERM_PROGRAM => vscode
    TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION => 1.52.0
    LANG => de_DE.UTF-8
    COLORTERM => truecolor

    PHP Variables

    Variable => Value
    $_SERVER['ALLUSERSPROFILE'] => C:\ProgramData
    $_SERVER['APPDATA'] => C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Roaming
    $_SERVER['CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME'] => \\.\pipe\crashpad_828_XYPHVDMQVQHPQSLA
    $_SERVER['CommonProgramFiles'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
    $_SERVER['CommonProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    $_SERVER['CommonProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
    $_SERVER['COMPUTERNAME'] => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    $_SERVER['ComSpec'] => C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
    $_SERVER['DriverData'] => C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
    $_SERVER['HOMEDRIVE'] => C:
    $_SERVER['HOMEPATH'] => \Users\Grkem
    $_SERVER['LOCALAPPDATA'] => C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local
    $_SERVER['LOGONSERVER'] => \\DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    $_SERVER['NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'] => 4
    $_SERVER['OneDrive'] => C:\Users\Grkem\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Bielefeld
    $_SERVER['OneDriveCommercial'] => C:\Users\Grkem\OneDrive - Fachhochschule Bielefeld
    $_SERVER['ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP'] => undefined
    $_SERVER['OS'] => Windows_NT
    $_SERVER['Path'] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020a\bin;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\gstreamer-ivao\bin;C:\gstreamer-ivao\x86\bin;C:\Users\Grkem\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Grkem\.dotnet\tools
    $_SERVER['PATHEXT'] => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
    $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE'] => AMD64
    $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER'] => Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
    $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_LEVEL'] => 6
    $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_REVISION'] => 9e09
    $_SERVER['ProgramData'] => C:\ProgramData
    $_SERVER['ProgramFiles'] => C:\Program Files
    $_SERVER['ProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)
    $_SERVER['ProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files
    $_SERVER['PSModulePath'] => C:\Users\Grkem\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
    $_SERVER['PUBLIC'] => C:\Users\Public
    $_SERVER['SESSIONNAME'] => Console
    $_SERVER['SystemDrive'] => C:
    $_SERVER['SystemRoot'] => C:\WINDOWS
    $_SERVER['TEMP'] => C:\Users\GRKEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    $_SERVER['TMP'] => C:\Users\GRKEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
    $_SERVER['USERDOMAIN'] => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    $_SERVER['USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE'] => DESKTOP-1GCBMNO
    $_SERVER['USERNAME'] => Grkem
    $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'] => C:\Users\Grkem
    $_SERVER['windir'] => C:\WINDOWS
    $_SERVER['TERM_PROGRAM'] => vscode
    $_SERVER['TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION'] => 1.52.0
    $_SERVER['LANG'] => de_DE.UTF-8
    $_SERVER['COLORTERM'] => truecolor
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] => 
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =>
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] =>
    $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] =>
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] =>
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1607948677.3428
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1607948677
    $_SERVER['argv'] => Array
    (
    )

    $_SERVER['argc'] => 0

    PHP License
    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
    and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
    questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```